# Two dimensional array error while printing array : array index out of bond

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class TwoDarray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int a[][] = new int[2][2];
        a[0][0] = 0;    a[0][1] = 1;    a[0][2] = 2;
        a[1][0] = 3;    a[1][1] = 4;    a[1][2] = 5;
        a[2][0] = 6;    a[2][1] = 7;    a[2][2] = 8;
        for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=2;j++)
            {
                System.out.print("\t"+a[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();

        }

    }
}
```

I'm using eclipse and it gives error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
>   at TwoDarray.main(TwoDarray.java:7)

I think my code is ok! but please suggest if I had done somthing wrong...

In one book they give structured form of array.[image: twoDarray]

and for that following code is also given: 
[image]

**My structure of array is just similar to this only I have 2 rows and 2 columns.**

Comment: do `int[][] a = new int[3][3];` The number you give is the size of the array, not the last index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes are one-larger when initializing arrays:

```
int a[][] = new int[3][3];
```

Comment: As per your suggestion I change my code to `int a[][] = new int[3][3];` it works fine. but why we need to initialize array than one..? In one book I read that If we have to create array[4][5], then it will need the line `int a[][] = new int[4][5];` so In my case `int[2][2]` is correct so why this code gives error...?

Comment: As the others noted - when you create the array, the numbers indicate how many items the array will have starting from 1. When you use it, the index is starts from 0. This creates a silly 1-off error which is a headache for a lot of programmers.

Answer (score 3):

If you array is of size `n` then the maximum index it has is `n-1`. You have array of size `2`, so the max index is `1`, but you try to access index `2`.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare your array : `int a[][] = new int[2][2];`

The `int[2]` means you'll have 2 cases of memory, so `a[0]` and `a[1]`.
And then you're trying to reach `a[2]`, causing the error.

You must declare :

```
int a[][] = new int[2][2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[][] = new int[R][C];
```

here R represents the Row and C represents the Column

```
hence a[2][2]
```

2 rows with 2 column

update your code with

```
int a[][] = new int[3][3];
```